# windows - batch - for (can somebody explain How does this code work?)

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

windows - batch - for (can somebody explain How does this code work?)

```
@echo off

for /f %%i in ('dir f* /s /aD /b 2^> nul ^| find "" /v /c') do set VAR=%%i

echo %VAR% > output.txt
```

[here is the output in this directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4FUy.png)

Comment: I commend to your attention [SS64 on `FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: `dir` lists all files starting with an `f` (`dir /?` tells you about the used switches), the output is captured by `find` which counts the lines (a.k.a files) (again, `find /?` for more info). The `for /f` loop captures (`for /?`) the result and sets it to a variable (`set /?`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[1] Execute `dir f* /s /aD /b` - this lists all names-only (`/b`) in the directory and in subdirectories (`/s`) that are directories (`/ad`) and match the name-mask `f*`
[2] 2^> nul - suppress error messages (ie - no matching names found)
[3] ^| - send the output of the `dir` command to `find`
[4] find "" /v /c - find any line that does not (`/v`) contain *nothing* (`""`) and output the count of such lines (`/c`)
[5] The resultant count-string is assigned to `%%i` by the `for` command
[6] And then to the variable by the `set`

The caret (`^`) tells `cmd` that the symbol following is part of the command to be executed, not of the `for`.

See `for /?`, `dir /?`, `find /?` and `set /?` from the prompt for details, or thousands of examples on SO.

Comment: So it outputs the number of subfolders in the current folder.

Comment: @THEJOATMON : should do. Possibly not subdirectories per se, but the count of all subdirectories, sub-subdirectories, sub-sub-subdirectories and so on, not just the number of subirectories contained within the target directory.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said recursively.